# Log Can't be truncated but no CDCs or Replication exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

We restored databases to our `UAT` environment and set up `AlwaysOn`.  Whenever I try and backup the log I'm getting "The log was not truncated because records at the beginning of the log are pending replication or Change Data Capture. Ensure the Log Reader Agent or capture job is running or use `sp_repldone` to mark transactions as distributed or captured."

I've removed CDCs from the database and removed all replication but I'm still getting the above error.  The `log_reuse_wait_desc` is showing up as `AVAILABILITY_REPLICA` or `REPLICATION`.

I've also tried running the following.

```
EXEC sys.sp_replflush

EXEC sp_removedbreplication

EXEC sp_repldone @xactid = NULL, @xact_segno = NULL, @numtrans = 0,     @time = 0, @reset = 1
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it

Comment: Check out the DBCC LOGINFO command. There might be some virtual log files which are still used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The production database, which is what this DB was restored from, does have replication set up.  Even though this copy was restored without any replication there was a transaction in the log still from prod.  To fix this I set up a new publication with one table from the problem database, didn't even create a subscription, then deleted the publication and the problem went away.

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

Running the below solved the problem for us:

```
use myDB
go

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db 
go

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_db 
go

EXEC sp_removedbreplication myDB
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem (SQL 2012) - a prod database set as a replication publisher, and using a restored copy in a lab environment where we don't use replication. Found this solution [here](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/security/da-DK/c96f3cb4-5f4e-49a4-a84a-6e2cd46915a3/quotthe-log-was-not-truncated-because-records-at-the-beginning-of-the-log-are-pending?forum=sqlreplication):

`EXEC sp_replicationdboption 'MyDB','publish','true',1`

If you get a

> ~"distributor not configured" error,

your server may not be set up to manage replication. To get past this you can just make your server a distributor:

In SSMS: Server name: Right click on Replication, and walk through the steps to set up a distributor. Local machine should be OK.

```
EXEC sp_repldone @xactid = NULL, @xact_segno = NULL, @numtrans = 0,    @time = 0, @reset = 1

EXEC sp_replicationdboption 'MyDB','publish','false',1
```

Re-running the log backup after this was much faster and the hanging log record(s) were cleared.